# Want to use String functions in the data returned from the API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, string, api

I want to use String functions like *slice(x,y), length()* in the data returned from the API.

I had converted the data using `JSON.stringfy(obj)` into a variable `mystr` and uses the string function. But whenever the page reloads/renders, the console shows

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`

i.e. is unable to recognise the string methods.

#### Code Below

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';

const TimeZoneComponent = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const timeZone = () => {
    fetch("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata")
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((json)=>{
        console.log(json);
        setData(json);
    })
}

useEffect(()=> {
        timeZone();
},[])

let mystr = JSON.stringify(data.datetime);

return(
    <div className="timezone">       
        Date: {mystr.slice(1,10)} <br/>
        Time: {mystr.slice(12,13)} <br/>
        Timezone: {data.timezone}
    </div>
);

}

export default TimeZoneComponent;
```

I am trying to display time and date separately. How can I improve ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the initial state `data` is `[]`. When before api call success and return value, `mystr` is  `undefined`. So you can update like this to fix by using conditional (ternary) operator:

```
<div className="timezone">       
    Date: {mystr?.slice(1,10)} <br/>
    Time: {mystr?.slice(12,13)} <br/>
    Timezone: {data.timezone}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code I only see you setting the variable "myStr" once when running the code

```
let mystr = JSON.stringify(data.datetime);
```

I assume at that time data.datetime is undefined and JSON.stringify(undefined) also returns undefined.
I assume you plan to fill data with the result of your timezone-fetch. You already call

```
setData(json);
```

I don't see the code of that function in your example but you might use it to set the data variable to the json result like

```
data = json;
```

You might need to declare data as a let variable and not a constant (const) to re-assign it though

Comment: I am currently fecthing the data from API